# What is it called when I can't tilt my foot inwards?

Tags: ankle

Just for the record I am not asking for any exercises/physical therapy advices. I mainly want to know how I can describe the situation with a medical term. Like a word for it.

I had an ankle sprain on my RIGHT foot a while ago. The thing is that I can tilt my foot inwards when standing, no problem. It's nearly the same as on the other foot. But when going into a knees over toes squat, I can't bend it inwards. Now, I have had an overpronation my whole life on both feet. When squatting I can as a result go with my knees way more over my toes than without it. Coming to my point: Due to my ankle sprain, I don't have overpronation on my right foot IN THE squat position anymore. That makes squatting a weird experience as I have to do something with my left foot to perform a nice squat. I feel like the outside of my foot near the fibula (where it's reaching out) is hindering this inwards movement.

What's the medical term for this not-being-able-to-tilt-the-foot-inward thing? So I may find something on google about it.

Comment: I have a suspicion there is no accepted term for what you describe. What you're describing is really just a lingering symptom of your sprain, and it's probably rather unique to you and this particular injury.

Comment: But that seems so impossible. I dont want to be rude of course, when you say it, I value it of course. But so far I have found a lot concerning symptoms after a sprain you know...so...

Comment: By all means keep reading up on sprains; you may find this condition described. I'm just saying I think there's a good chance there's no single term for it. It would likely just be described by doctors using standard anatomic and orthopedic language rather than a unique term. I could of course be wrong.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?https://certifiedfoot.com/inversion-ankle-sprains-athelete/